# customize AllItems.aspx for existing list in sp2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have SP site/list in production.
My task is to add new column and that column will be link to document library's folder.
So on allItems.aspx I have to show image and when user will click on that image it will go that document library folder.
I have added column with HREF but now my task is edit AllItems.aspx and show image for new column.

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Please describe your question in more detail, not sure what you are asking here...

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize AllItems.aspx, you can do the same by editing the page in SharePoint Designer 2010.

Open SP 2010 designer, open the site, on the Site Objects, click on "Lists and Libraries"

Click on the Lists that you want to modify

In the views section, there will be a file called "AllItems.aspx"

Right Click the page and click on "Edit File in Advanced Mode"

Now you can add the new link that will open a document library that you want to associate to

Let me know whether this answer your question